# How to convert a line graph into data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, charts, import

Am looking for a tool that will import a line graph (chart) image and convert the line into numerical data, either in a spreadsheet or a database. For example, given an image like this:

[image: Line graph]

It might prompt to find out what colour the line is (or the user clicks on part of it) and then it would do the rest, e.g. importing numbers into a column in an Excel workbook. Not too worried about it knowing the scale, just the changes - can easily rescale the data.

Does anyone know if such a tool already exists in any shape or form? If not, it's going down on my list of things to do if I ever have time...

Answer (score 1):

Just found one:

http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/app/

Does basically what I asked and exports the data to CSV.
After watching the help video I've worked out how to use it and it's working great!